# mypy error when aliasing Callable with TypeAlias

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Suppose we have the following Python 3 code:

```
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeAlias


class BaseContext:
    ...


Params = ParamSpec("Params")


def reset_command_context(
    _func: Callable[Concatenate[BaseContext, Params], None],
    *,
    current: bool = False,
) -> None:
    ...


@reset_command_context
def process_invite_unique(ctx: BaseContext, unique: bool) -> None:
    ...


@reset_command_context
def process_ban(ctx: BaseContext) -> None:
    ...
```

then I run static type checkers:

```
~ $ pyright test.py 
WARNING: there is a new pyright version available (v1.1.330 -> v1.1.330.post0).                                                                                                               
Please install the new version or set PYRIGHT_PYTHON_FORCE_VERSION to `latest`                                                                                                                                   

0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations                                                                                                                                                                             
~ $ mypy test.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Seems that we're all OK. But let's define the `TypeAlias` for our `Callable` and then annotate `_func` argument in `reset_command_context` decorator using that alias:

```
FuncSpec: TypeAlias = Callable[Concatenate[BaseContext, Params], None]


def reset_command_context(
    _func: FuncSpec,
    *,
    current: bool = False,
) -> None:
    ...
```

Running static type checkers now shows different result. `pyright` is still OK, but `mypy` blames:

```
~ $ mypy test.py                                                                                                                                                             
test2.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "reset_command_context" has incompatible type "Callable[[BaseContext, bool], None]"; expected "Callable[[BaseContext, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], None]"  [arg-type]
test2.py:20: note: This is likely because "process_invite_unique" has named arguments: "ctx". Consider marking them positional-only
test2.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "reset_command_context" has incompatible type "Callable[[BaseContext], None]"; expected "Callable[[BaseContext, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], None]"  [arg-type]
test2.py:25: note: This is likely because "process_ban" has named arguments: "ctx". Consider marking them positional-only
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is this a bug in `mypy` or did I do something the wrong way?

Comment: `FuncSpec` is generic. `_func: FuncSpec` is the same as writing `_func: FuncSpec[Any]`. It looks like you want `_func: FuncSpec[Params]`, which indeed passes type checking with mypy

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What is not actually true? You made `FuncSpec` a generic type alias by using `Params` in it.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the return type of `reset_command_context` so that it returns a callable with the trailing parameter spec of `_func`?

Comment: I really don't understand why ``FuncSpec`` is generic. It's a ``TypeAlias`` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) and should be able to be used as a very readable code substitute.

Comment: See [User defined generic types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types) on that same page. Using any TypeVar variant (TypeVar, TypeVarTuple, ParamSpec) inside a type alias makes it generic.

Comment: Well, generic types are a very different thing from what I'm asking about, isn't it? My question is about the definition of a ``Callable`` which can be used in-place or as a ``TypeAlias`` substitute, and thus causes different ``mypy`` output.

Comment: `FuncSpec` is generic because it has a free type variable (`Params`). If you had `T = TypeVar("T"); MyListType: TypeAlias = list[T]`, `MyListType` is generic as well (because you provided the free type variable `T` to the alias, instead of a concrete type like `int`).

Comment: Whether pyright warns you about this is dependent on whether you [turned on the `pyright: strict` directive](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?gzip=H4sIALtLJGUC_52RwWrDMAyG734KkV6S4eUBAhvbCj2OwXYrJSiu0hkc27Oc0rz9XGelGetpBiP4Jf2fLK_AT0EfPmMDHINWUYg-uAHi5LU9gB68CxHWaAx2hiSsnVUYyaYr4Q0DDu-elISPydOz0chCCGWQGV6QKVVHOsVGQDp1Xadk7mF4uDaXxawVldiMVp2l5uqXKi_07QK-Xdj_DMI7Ca_O0k6IPfUQiCm2yg0D2n2KubTMk7R94jRwocks3s1BjSGQTevonDMJvkHDJEUF94_ZffmWp5uMTPfBKWJutT3qSO1o9ddIpYqnBn5NPidm2n8ZHdo_zje9Ah0JTZv-lspFcwWwygsH10OxSBSgGYqzSyG-AXMEltUpAgAA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FuncSpec` is a generic type alias, since you used a type variable (`ParamSpec`) in its definition.

Wherever you use `FuncSpec`, you can parametrize it with a parameter specification --- either a concrete one or another `ParamSpec`. For example,

- `FuncSpec[[int, str, float]]`,
- `FuncSpec[...]`, or
- `FuncSpec[Params]`.

If you don't explicitly parametrize it, your type checker will treat it as `FuncSpec[Any]`.

In this case, mypy is correct to reject your code. You hinted `reset_command_context` to accept a `FuncSpec[Any]`, which is callable that is allowed to be called with a `BaseContext` positional argument and *any number of additional positional and keyword arguments*. Neither `process_invite_unique` nor `process_ban` can bind with that signature, since they can't accept arbitrarily more arguments. You'd need to given them `ctx: BaseContext, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any` signatures for them to work with  `reset_command_context` as written (and indeed, if you make that change, they do).

It looks like what you actually want is one of two things:

1. **You want `FuncSpec` do denote a callable that accepts a `BaseContext` and any number of additional arguments.** You don't care about specializing it or "catching" the parameter specification of those additional arguments.

   If this is the case, what you want is `FuncSpec[...]`:

   ```py
   def reset_command_context(
       _func: FuncSpec[...],
       *,
       current: bool = False,
   ) -> None:
   ```

   This will pass type checking as written, but will give both `process_invite_unique` and `process_ban` the type `None`, which probably is not what you want.
2. **You want to "capture" the parameter specification of `_func` are re-use it in the signature of `reset_command_context`.**

   Say you want `reset_command_context` to return a callable with the trailing parameter specification of `_func` with the `BaseContext` popped off the front. That can be expressed using your existing `Params` type variable as

   ```
   def reset_command_context(
       _func: FuncSpec[Params],
       *,
       current: bool = False,
   ) -> Callable[Params, None]:
   ```

   This will give `process_invite_unique` the type `Callable[[bool], None` and `process_ban` the type `Callable[[], None]`. You can verify this with `reveal_type`:

   ```
   @reset_command_context
   def process_invite_unique(ctx: BaseContext,  unique: bool) -> None:
       ...


   @reset_command_context
   def process_ban(ctx: BaseContext) -> None:
       ...

   reveal_type(process_invite_unique)
   reveal_type(process_ban)
   ```

   This [produces the mypy output](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=bd4c1d105a9ba3a661db89d7cd6fbc0b):

   ```
   main.py:32: note: Revealed type is "def (unique: builtins.bool)"
   main.py:33: note: Revealed type is "def ()"
   Success: no issues found in 1 source file
   ```

Comment: Thanks!
Your explanation about having to parametrize ``FuncSpec`` was crucial to me!